# Regex to match none, one, the other or both in any order

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find an appropriate expressions to match C++ integer suffix, which is, following [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> integer-suffix, if provided, may contain one or both of the following > (if both are provided, they may appear in any order:
>
> - unsigned-suffix (the character u or the character U)
> - long-suffix (the character l or the character L) or the long-long-suffix (the character sequence ll or the character sequence LL) (since C++11)

As of now, the best pattern I was able to write is

```
/u?(ll|l)?u?/i
```

But this will match `uu` which isn't allowed per the standard… Is there a better regex?

**edit**

In the lexer I'm currently working on, we parse integers as follows (C rules, C++ rules are similar):

```
rule /\d+[lu]*/i, Num::Integer
rule /0[0-7]+[lu]*/i, Num::Oct
rule /\d+[lu]*/i, Num::Integer
```

As one can see, the matching of the suffix is matching a lot more than what is defined in the standard. My goal is to rewrite this as:

```
isuffix = /u?(ll|l)?u?/i
rule /\d+#{isuffix}/i, Num::Integer
rule /0[0-7]+#{isuffix}/i, Num::Oct
rule /\d+#{isuffix}/i, Num::Integer
```

Comment: Try `/\b(?:ll|LL|[uU]|[lL])\b/`

Comment: The `i` at the end makes it case insensitive, but I'l give a try to the `?:`  !

Comment: I suggested a version to be used without `/i`. Or do you need to match `lL` and `uU`, `Uu`, `Ll`?

Comment: From the standard, I'd say `uLL` is acceptable, it's thought for rouge syntax highlighter so not for a compiler, something as close as possible would work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your pattern won't match unsigned long, no? Like `ULL`?

Comment: To match those add an optional u - `/\b(?:u?(?:ll|LL)|[uU]|[lL])\b/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130133/discussion-between-vser-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer

If you're looking for suffix so that `/\d('?\d)*#{suffix}/` matches decimal integers, you can use :

```
suffix = /(ul?l?|ll?u?)?\b/i
```

[Here](http://www.rubular.com/r/825mdKfJ9q) is a Rubular example. It matches `1` in `l1` and `11` in `c++11` though, because there's no lookbehind before `\d`.

## Old answers

This will find a non-empty suffix anywhere in the string :

```
/(?<![a-z])(ul?l?|ll?u?)\b/i
```

It means :

- `u`, `ul`, `ull` or
- `l`, `ll`, `lu` or `llu`

Followed by a word boundary and preceded by anything but another letter.

Other answers without boundaries match `"uu"` for example.

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/zYkAHzko85) is a Rubular example.

If your string is just the suffix and you want to check it is correct :

```
/^(ul?l?|ll?u?)?$/i
```

[Here](http://www.rubular.com/r/TjmJyRK4IC) is another example.

Comment: You won't match an empty suffix, add a `?` ;)

Comment: Are you just testing the suffix, and nothing else? If the match can be empty, it will basically match any string.

Comment: No, I'm working on a PR to a syntax highlighter (https://github.com/jneen/rouge/pull/578) where, for example, decimal integers are searched as `/\d('?\d)*[lu]*/i`, I'm trying to enhance the suffix matching and factorize it in a separate expression like `suffix=/(ul?l?|ll?u?)?\b/i` to match `/\d('?/d)*#{suffix}`.

Comment: Thanks. This would have been a valuable information in the question ;)

Comment: I was hesitating, I made the question as broad as possible to allow finding it for different purposes. But I can edit the OP to make my goal clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Ruby... U knoL

```
%w(u ul ull l ll llu).include? suffix.downcase
```

---

But if you insist:

```
/u?ll?|l?l?u/i
```

- The first part handles the `u` before the `l`s and requires an `l`.
- The second part handles the `u` after the `l`s and requires the `u`.

If you want to include an empty suffix as a possibility, you can add optional matching for these characters as well.

**Note that this expects that the lexer will fail if there are some leftovers from the suffix.**

---

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/lHEooVA3My)

Comment: @EricDuminil, how so? Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: You're the one with the accepted answer as avatar, you should know.

Comment: That was an example of String matched by your Regex ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil, consider the context. OP's initial regex obviously didn't try to exclude random strings. He said himself that his only problem is that he matches `uu`. That should lead us to believe that he has already left only the suffix part and wants to see if it follows the rule. The suffix shouldn't be random sentences.

Comment: @EricDuminil I couldn't find any counterexample (except a blank suffix that is avoided by adding a `?` after the closing parentheses. Is there anything I couldn't think of?

Comment: @VSer : ndn didn't have any boundary. His regex matched "uu" for example.

Comment: @ndn could you comment a bit more your first solution. And yes, I insist, it's for a lexer that is written with ruby regex ;)

Comment: @Vser it downcases the string and checks if it consists only of `u`s and `l`s. It explicitly fails the `uu` and `lul` cases.

Answer (score 1):

Force failing using negative lookahead.
For example:

```
/(?!u(ll|l)?u)u?(ll|l)?u?/i
```

or

```
/(?!ul*u)u?l{0,2}u?/i
```

Comment: It will match `ULLU` and `ULU` too which are one U too much. Is there a possiblity to avoid that?

Comment: Right. Corrected it.

Comment: Now I guess you will match `uu` again but I think this could be correctable!

Comment: It's a pretty good answer (and one of the shortest!) and it works quite well. Though there is something strange. If I type `UU` as a suffix (which is false of course), the previous char gets out of the match as in http://www.rubular.com/r/zKCQqiiizY, any idea to why?

Comment: @Vser That's because the last digit *is* followed by `ul*u`. A minimal example would be testing `/a+(?!b)/` against `aaabbb`. In this example the last a isn't matched, because of the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents for what ever it's worth: Sometimes it just pays to be explicit and not try to be too fancy. I think that this is one of those times. Here's my regex:

```
/(?<=\d)(u|ul|ull|l|lu|ll|llu)(?=([^ul]|$))/i
```

Well the idea was simple...

Comment: You still need some boundary around it.

Comment: Sorry, it's the longest pattern :)

Comment: Oh? This was a shortest regex contest? To think I was going for the clearest regex. Not saying I won that either, but it was my goal.

Comment: I agree that clarity is very important, and a few characters more are no biggie if it is easier to understand the regex and to find bugs.

Comment: I admit clarity is important, but in choosing the accepted answer (which I haven't done yet, it's not that easy, ndn and Eric have pretty close answers), I have to go for a rule and length appeared to me to be a good argument (it's clearly more measurable than clarity). But thanks again for your answer!